# Request for Custom Reporting on the Web

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, crystal-reports

I have had a request where a user wants the ability to create their own reports. I have developed and MVC4 application and it currently uses Crystal Reports to generate a pdf of the report.

Obviously Crystal reports allows the developer to drag an element anywhere on the screen. The user now wants to be able to create their own reports and have the ability to move the controls around to where they wish.

Is this possible at all and/or are there any variations to Crystal reports that will allow this? Ideally this will need to be done on the Web too!!

Any direction would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: Customers always ask for this.  It's an enormous pain in the ass to get right, and customers never use it anyway because it's still too hard, so you wind up making custom reports for them anyway.  A better approach is to evaluate their reporting requirements, implement a set of "close-enough" reports, and give them plenty of customization options to choose from (like which fields to include).  See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for the response, it is not so much the changing of the data and the report data source will be the same, they just want the ability to position the elements, is this still such a big task?

Comment: Does Crystal Reports have Excel output? They can rearrange the columns any way they want.

Comment: Hi Rob, that is not a solution I'm afraid. I am thinking about a HTML option using Jquery.

Comment: http://hexatech.com/viewidget/index.htm